# How to run code after authenticating with Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm application (SPA) that uses Azure AD authentication to authenticate users using the out of the box scaffolding that the new project command creates:

e.g.

```
 dotnet new blazorwasm -au SingleOrg --client-id "<app id>" -o BlazorSample --tenant-id "<tenant id>"
```

The application needs to run code after authenticating with Azure AD. It also needs access to the access token from Azure AD.

Is there a way for my code to be called after the authentication stack has authenticated a user?

Comment: Can you not use the cascaded `AuthenticationState`?  When `IsAuthenticated` run your code.   You don't indicate in your question when you want to get this information, You can use the `AuthenticationStateProvider` service to get the `ClaimsPrincipal` which contains all the user information provided by the authenticator.  See MS-Docs  -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authenticationstateprovider-service

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes i am doing this currently on the index page, but I thought their might be a central place I could detect once authentication was complete and hook it there vs. on each page.

Comment: If I read your comment correctly, the "central place" is the `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  The event is `AuthenticationStateChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the options for authentication on startup, you can provide a method to run once the ticket is received.

```
services.Configure(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>)(options =>
{
     options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context =>
     { 
          var tokens = context.Result.Ticket.Properties.GetTokens();
          context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<SomeService>();
          //do work here
     };
}));
```

Comment: Is this applicable in a blazor wasm app?  When I add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package to get OpenIdConnectDefaults etc... it completely breaks the project and wont compile.  This repos with a new project freshly created.